# How do I find out if any values are on more than 4 rows? (AMATEUR)

Tags: mysql, sql, count, inner-join, aggregate-functions

```
select tr.routeID, tr.`Start`, tr.Destination, to2.OperatorID, to3.Name 
from tbl_route tr 
inner join tbl_operatorrouterelation to2 
on tr.RouteID = to2.RouteID 
inner join tbl_operatordesc to3 
on to2.OperatorID = to3.OperatorID
```

This code gives back this table:

[image]

How can I find out which Names are on more than 4 rows and return the number of rows they're on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want aggregation:

```
select o.Name, count(*) as cnt  
from tbl_operatordesc o
inner join tbl_operatorrouterelation orr on orr.OperatorID = o.OperatorID
inner join tbl_route r on r.RouteID = orr.RouteID   
group by o.OperatorID
having count(*) > 4
```

The `group by` clause assumes that `OperatorID` is the primary key of `tbl_operatordesc`. If that's not the case you would need to change add `o.Name` in that clause, like:

```
group by o.OperatorID, o.Name
```